# Tagging and references for the tag descriptions

Tags: discussion, tagging

Is there guidance on writing / editing tag descriptions for NE-SX?

Today, I noticed some are in need of correction or updates.  I would include URLs to resources, like IETF RFCs, vendor concept docs, or Wikipedia pages, if this is appropriate.  However, I'm not sure that's desirable and haven't noticed if any tag explanations do have such pointers for sourcing or further reading.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for taking the time to make this site better! Please suggest improvements on tag descriptions. As described in [this post on meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214337/what-is-a-tag-wiki-how-do-i-write-a-good-one), links to external resources can be included. That post contains some nice hints on how to write good tag descriptions, so it's worth checking that before starting.